# Why does it print the window object instead of printing the date object?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code. I would expect `this` to   be date instead of the window object. I am running this in Firefox scratchpad. What am I missing?

[This image describes the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERtJ8.jpg)

```js
Date.prototype.nextDay = function() {
  console.log('Printing this ' + this);
  var currentdate = this.getDate();
  return new Date(this.setDate(currentdate + 1));
}
(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  document.write(date);
  document.write(date.nextDay());
})();
```

Comment: It prints a date when I run your code.

Comment: Yeah .. But it should print the next day date too . it doesnt do that

Comment: i see three dates, and one is set to tomorrow...

Comment: That's what I see, too.

Comment: @tushru2004, which version of which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox scratchpad . I also get the same result when i use live preview in brackets

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: its version 41.0.2 . I have directly copy the pasted the entire code and hit run in scratchpad

Comment: it's working, I updated your question.. please take a look

Comment: Ok its not for me. See the screen shot that i have updated. I am definitely making some conceptual mistake. Not sure what

Comment: Try putting a `;` after the `}` in line 5 of your screenshot.  You have a semicolon in the *question*, but not in your screenshot.  That may be the issue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat  thanks that worked. But why ?

Answer (score 2):

You have run afoul of JavaScript's insidious automatic semicolon insertion (or in this case, lack thereof).

What you thought were two separate statements:

```
Date.prototype.nextDay = function () { ... }
```

and

```
(function () { ... })();
```

are being interpreted as one single statement:

```
Date.prototype.nextDay = function () { ... }(function () { ... })();
```

Your first anonymous function is being called immediately with your second anonymous function as its argument.

Since it is not being called as the method of any object, and since you are not running in strict mode, `this` is evaluating to the global object. And that explains the behavior you are seeing.

Having an opening parenthesis at the beginning of a line is one of the few places where the JavaScript parser will fail to "guess" that you wanted to end the previous statement. [People who avoid semicolons as much as possible](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) will generally make a point to precede any statement-starting parentheses with a semicolon:

```
Date.prototype.nextDay = function () {
    console.log('Printing this ' + this)
    var currentdate = this.getDate()
    return new Date(this.setDate(currentdate + 1))
}
;(function () {
    var date = new Date()
    console.log(date)
    console.log(date.nextDay())
})()
```